# Access followers data Laravel 5.8 and Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a base table setup for followers and the Follower model has the relationship belongsTo with User model. User model has the relationship belongsToMany with the Follower model. The followers table has "id, follower_id, leader_id"

I'm trying to access the followers table through the User model but it won't let me do it. I must be doing something wrong, but I have worked with Eloquent relationships before and I have always had it working then. Can someone take a look at the code snippets below and point out what is wrong?

User Model

```
 public function followers(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'leader_id', 'follower_id')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function followings(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'followers', 'follower_id', 'leader_id')->withTimestamps();
```

Follower model

```
protected $table = 'followers';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

FollowerController

```
Old controller for old relationship
// public function followUser($id){
    //     $user = User::find($id);

    //     if(!$user){
    //         return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'User does not exist.');
    //     }

    //     $user->followers()->attach(auth()->user()->id);

    //     return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'You now follow the user!');
    // }


//New controller
    public function followUser($id){
        $user = User::find($id);
        if(!$user){
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'User does not exist.');
            }

            $follow = new Follower;
            $follow->follower_id = Auth::user()->id;
            $follow->leader_id = $user;

            $follow->save();
            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'You now follow the user!');

    }
```

UserController

```
 // This is a test function
    public function index($id){
        $userid = Auth::user();
        $user = User::find($id)->followers;
        $recipe = Recipe::find(5);
        $savedRecipes = Save::where('user_id', '=', $userid);

        return view('welcome')->with('recipe', $recipe)->with('user', $user)->with('savedRecipes', $savedRecipes);

    }
```

Test View

```
 <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    Welcome to the TestLab: {{$user->followers->follower_id}}
                    <br>
```

This throws an error of "Property not found on this instance". 
All the namespacing is all in order so that is not the issue either. 
What is the problem here?

Comment: a follower belongs to a user and a user has many followers, right?

Comment: should I not use belongsToMany there?

Comment: only if a user has many followers and a follower has many users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a **One To Many** relationship between users and followers you defined your relationship wrong, if a follower belongs to a User, a User **hasMany** followers:

```
 public function followers(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Follower','user_id');
 }
```

Take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Your controller:

```
public function index($id){
     $user = User::find($id);
     return view('welcome')->with('user', $user);
}
```

You could access each follower from a user using a foreach loop:

```
@foreach($user->followers as $follower)
    {{$follower->anyAttributeFromTheFollower}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: The issue is, the foreach loop returns an empty array. There is nothing returned when I try to access each follower_id, even though I can see that it is there in the DB table.

Comment: make sure you send the $user to the view. Try doing this: ```$user->followers->first()->id ``` you should receive the id from the first follower

Comment: That is returning "Trying to get property of non-object". Somewhere I am missing to connect something. The $user is being passed to the view. I can retrieve any attribute on the users table with $user->anyAttribute. But it is not letting me get anything from followers....

Comment: This is weird, you changed the relation i writed in my answer? Try using:```return $this->hasMany('App\Follower','user_id');```

Comment: Now it's working!! That was it! Thanks a million Lucas. You might want to update the model method in your answer to include what you wrote in your last comment in case somebody else has the same problem! Thanks again!